# How to limit number of records from associated model

Tags: cakephp, associations

In a simple CakePHP model where User hasMany Item (and Item belongsTo User)-
Suppose 50 users, have each 10 items.
How can I find() only 5 users, each with the latest 5 items he has?
When I impose a limit in the find, it only limits the number of users, not the number of associated Items.

Answer (score 7):

Just spec the **limit** attribute in your hasMany model declaration.

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className'     => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
        'conditions'    => array('Comment.status' => '1'),
        'order'    => 'Comment.created DESC',
        'limit'        => '5',
        'dependent'=> true
    )
);
```

(Appropriate props to the [CakePHP Book page](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1043/hasMany) that I stole this code from.)

Comment: Link expired. New link - http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany

Comment: When i am using limit with hasmany then separate query for every row will  executed. But i would like to execute only 1 query for hasmany with limit

Comment: `limit` attribute is removed from HMBTM relation mappings in CakePHP3. Any alternatives??

Answer (score 5):

An option. In your controller:

```
$this->User->hasMany['Item']['limit'] = 1;
```

This will limit the number of items. I didn't test the order, but this should work:

```
$this->User->hasMany['Item']['order'] = 'Item DESC';
```