# How to make div align="center" via DOM?

Tags: dom, html

I have an HTML code:

```
<div id="first"></div>
```

I wish to use javascript (document.findElementById) to change the behavior of the div so that it'll be as:

```
<div id="first" align="center"></div>
```

How do I go about that?

Comment: e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942250/cakephp-how-to-limit-number-of-records-from-associated-model

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("first").setAttribute("align", "center");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`element.setAttribute`<sup>MDN</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)

```
document.getElementById('first').setAttribute('align', 'center');
```

A less archaic approach is to [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) the margin:

```
document.getElementById('first').style.margin = '0 auto';
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/UySdJ/)

Answer (score 0):

This works if you already have an align attribute for that element

```
document.getElementById("first").attributes['align'] = 'center';
```

If you dont already have the attribute, use setAttribute

```
document.getElementById('first').setAttribute('align', 'center');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('first').align = center
```

See [How to add/update an attribute to an HTML element using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710275/how-to-add-update-an-attribute-to-an-html-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for you, the `align` attribute is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

You can center DIVs of specific widths by setting the style `margin` attributes, like so:

```
document.getElementById('first').style.marginLeft = 'auto';
document.getElementById('first').style.marginRight = 'auto';
```

If you're set on modifying the `align` attribute, you can do it like so:

```
document.getElementById('first').align = 'center';
```

Other ways to center DIVs (using CSS) can be found [here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).

Comment: Ha, but can you come up with CSS that accurately emulates the behaviour of `align="center"`? The page you link to barely scratches the surface.

Comment: What do you mean by accurately emulating the behavior of `align='center'`? Setting the margins to `auto` is one of the standard ways to do this.

Comment: No. Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFMyn/). If you remove the `align="center"`, giving the div `margin:0 auto` is not enough to make it behave as before! Neither is `text-align:center` or a combination of the two.

Comment: That's why in my original post I said "DIVs of specific widths." As soon as you give the div a CSS width in your JSFiddle, it works. This is a well-documented phenomenon (one workaround is [here](http://www.tightcss.com/centering/center_variable_width.htm).) While it's a shame that this occurs and it's nice that it doesn't with the `align='center'` technique, we're still faced with the fact that using `align` is deprecated.

Comment: Hm. With a fixed width, my jsfiddle still doesn't work the same with and without the align attribute. Am I overlooking something? Maybe I should post a new question.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I overlooked the specifics of your JSFiddle. What you want requires a smidge more CSS. In general, for block elements the `margin:0 auto;` is the way to go, and for text you want to use `text-align:center;`—see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPaXu/). Hope that helps!

As an extra note, check out the difference between adding `text-align:center;` to the styling for `p` (which emulates your fiddle), versus adding it to the style for the `div`.

Comment: No, `margin:0 auto` is not the way to go, because it would interfere with things like `<blockquote>` in the div, that have margins themselves. I'm still working on a definitive solution.

Comment: It's up to you, but `<blockquote>` is deprecated in favor of CSS margins.

Comment: WHAT?? You can't be serious! Where does it say that `<blockquote>` is deprecated? Hey, you do know what `<blockquote>` _means_, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. Use of `<blockquote>` purely as a means of indenting is deprecated—see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#edef-BLOCKQUOTE). If you're using it for actual block quotes you're fine.

In general, with all of the backwards-compatibility of browsers, you're still pretty much assured that deprecated elements will work just fine. ;)

Comment: Apology accepted. But I never hinted that I ever use any element in ways they weren't meant to be used - I wouldn't dare, _and_ it's not necessary - so your remark came as a bit of a surprise.